# Node.js Use Promise.all For returning asynchronous call?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am using cloud functions to query for posts. When the post is queried for, I set some updates for firebase after querying for some additional update for the post, as such:

```
 const getPostsForDate = admin.firestore().collection('posts').where('timeOfDeletion', '<', currentTime)
return getPostsForDate.get().then(snapshot => {
    const updates = {} 
    var counter = 0
    const batch = admin.firestore().batch()
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        var key = doc.id
        admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const convoIDCollection = snapshot.val()
                for (var child in convoIDCollection) {

                    console.log(child)
                    updates["conversations/" + child] = null
                    updates["messages/"+ child] = null
                    updates["convoID/"+ child] = null
                }
            }
            updates["/convoID/" + key] = null
            updates["/reveals/" + key] = null
            updates["/postDetails/" + key] = null
            const postFireStoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(key)
            const posterRef = admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(key)
            batch.delete(postFireStoreRef)
            batch.delete(posterRef)
            counter++
         })

    })
    if (counter > 0) {
        console.log("at the deletion")
          return Promise.all[admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()] 
    }
    else {
        console.log("null")
        return null
    }
})

})
```

The problem is, however, is that the query admin.database().ref('convoID/...) is asynchronous; thus, the updates are sent to the database empty and nothing changes. Now, the solution to this is promises, except implementing the promise.all with all the other returns is not going as expected. I have tried

```
 var promises = []
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        var key = doc.id
        promises.push(admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const convoIDCollection = snapshot.val()
                for (var child in convoIDCollection) {

                    console.log(child)
                    updates["conversations/" + child] = null
                    updates["messages/"+ child] = null
                    updates["convoID/"+ child] = null
                }
            }
            updates["/convoID/" + key] = null
            updates["/reveals/" + key] = null
            updates["/postDetails/" + key] = null
            const postFireStoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(key)
            const posterRef = admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(key)
            batch.delete(postFireStoreRef)
            batch.delete(posterRef)
            counter++
         })
        )
    })
promises.all(promises).then(() =>
     if (counter > 0) {
        console.log("at the deletion")
          return Promise.all[admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()] 
    }
    else {
        console.log("null")
        return null
    }
);
```

Except I receive the error `unexpected token if`, `Declaration or statement expected` In the end by the promises.all() Is this the correct way to wait for the asynchronous call to finish?

Comment: `Promise.all(promises).then(() => { code here });`.  Your code is using `promises.all()` instead of `Promise.all()` and, is missing `{` and `}` around the function body in the `.then()` handler.

Comment: And, `return Promise.all[]` should be `return Promise.all()`.  Are you really asking us to help you with all these basic syntax errors?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `admin.database().ref().once()` returns a promise?

Comment: @jfriend00 I’ll try your first comment out today, and I’m pretty sure thefatabase reference does return a promise

Comment: @jfriend00 `admin.database().ref().once()` doesn't return a promise. My confusion lies in how to combine the promise returned from  `return getPostsForDate.get().then(snapshot => {` along with the promises in the promises array I created.

Comment: Well, it appears from [the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) that if you don't pass it a callback, `.once()` does return a promise.  Use `.then()` with it instead of the regular callback.

Comment: @jfriend00, that seems correct. I've got it down to `return Promise.all(promises).then(() => { 
            if (counter > 0) {
                console.log("at the deletion")
                return Promise.all(admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit())
            }
            else {
                console.log("null")
                return null
            }
        })` But I am now getting `Avoid nesting promises.`

Comment: "Avoid nesting promises." just sounds like a lint warning.  Does the code actually run and work?

Comment: @jfriend00, After testing, the original problem persists. The console.log is returning null because it is not waiting for the query to finish as the query is asynchronous.

Comment: @jfriend00 Looks to be working now, just needed to push the promises. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap this question up, I'll attempt to summarize what we covered in comments:

**Fix arrow function definition.** Change this:

```
promises.all(promises).then(() => code here)
```

to this:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(() => { code here });
```

---

**And, fix calling of Promise.all().**  Change this:

```
return Promise.all[...]
```

to this:

```
return Promise.all([...])
```

---

**And, `admin.database().ref().once()` will return a promise, but only if you do NOT pass `.once()` a regular callback.**

So, change this:

```
promises.push(admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => { ...}));
```

to this:

```
promises.push(admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value').then(snapshot => {...}));
```

---

And, it's a little cleaner if you change the general structure of this:

```
let promises = [];
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   promises.push(...)
});
Promise.all(promises).then(...)
```

to this:

```
Promise.all(snapshot.map(doc => {
    return admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once(...).then(...);
})).then(...);
```